# Case Statement(conditional) with CTE

Tags: sql-server, function, conditional-statements, common-table-expression

I have a function which i am trying to convert to TVF.
But the problem i face is ,the function is multi parter ,with multiple IF conditions.

I was able to convert one condition to TVF and for that i have used CTE.(i received help from this forum earlier).
But when i tried to convert the entire function to TVF by including the conditional statements,i am having troubles.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEventDecisionDueDate]
(
       @EventNumber VARCHAR(20),
       @BaseId VARCHAR(25),
          @CheckDate BIT
)

RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @CurrentStatus VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @BaseDateTime DateTime
DECLARE @DecisionDueDate DateTime


SELECT @CurrentStatus = (SELECT cis.IncidentStatus
                                 FROM CurrentStatus cis 
                                 INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (cis.BaseId = r.Id)
                                 WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND r.BaseId = @BaseId)

SELECT @BaseDateTime = (SELECT BaseDateTime FROM Base r 
                          WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND r.BaseId = @BaseId)

IF @CurrentStatus IN ('0','6') AND @CheckDate = 1
BEGIN

       SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @BaseDateTime)

       WHILE @DecisionDueDate < getdate() 
             SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DecisionDueDate)

       DECLARE @FinalJournalDate DateTime

       SELECT @FinalJournalDate = (SELECT TOP 1 ij.Date
                                       FROM EventDetails_Journal ij 
                                       INNER JOIN EventJournal p ON ij.PageId = p.Id 
                                       INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                       INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                       WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber AND r.BaseId = @BaseId) AND ij.ReviewType = 'Supervisor Monthly Review' ORDER BY ij.Date DESC)

      IF(DATEADD(DAY, 30, @BaseDateTime) < getdate() AND
           (@FinalJournalDate is null OR DATEADD(DAY, 30, @FinalJournalDate) < getdate()) AND
              DATEADD(DAY, 14, @DecisionDueDate) > DATEADD(DAY, 30, getdate()))
                  SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, -30, @DecisionDueDate)
         ELSE IF((@FinalJournalDate is not null ) AND (DATEADD(DAY, 30, @FinalJournalDate) >= @DecisionDueDate))
                  SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DecisionDueDate)

END


IF @CurrentStatus IN ('0','6') AND @CheckDate = 0
BEGIN

       SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @BaseDateTime)

       WHILE @DecisionDueDate < getdate() 
             SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DecisionDueDate)

       DECLARE @Final30DayDecisonDate DateTime
       DECLARE @Final6MonthDecisonDate DateTime
       DECLARE @Final30DayJournalDate DateTime

       SELECT @Final30DayDecisonDate = (SELECT TOP 1  idps.BaseSupplementDate
                                                FROM EventDetails_Supplements idps 
                                                INNER JOIN EventDetails p ON idps.PageId = p.Id 
                                                INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                                INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                                WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND 
                                                             r.BaseId = @BaseId AND idps.IsThirtyDayReview = 1 ORDER BY idps.BaseSupplementDate DESC)

       SELECT @Final6MonthDecisonDate = (SELECT TOP 1  idps.BaseSupplementDate
                                                FROM EventDetails_Supplements idps 
                                                INNER JOIN EventDetails p ON idps.PageId = p.Id 
                                                INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                                INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                                WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND 
                                                             r.BaseId = @BaseId AND idps.IsSixMonthReview = 1 ORDER BY idps.BaseSupplementDate DESC)

       SELECT @Final30DayJournalDate = (SELECT TOP 1 ij.Date
                                       FROM EventDetails_Journal ij 
                                       INNER JOIN EventJournal p ON ij.PageId = p.Id 
                                       INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                       INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                       WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber AND r.BaseId = @BaseId) AND ij.ReviewType = '30-DAY' ORDER BY ij.Date DESC)

      IF(DATEADD(DAY, 30, @BaseDateTime) < getdate() AND
           (@Final30DayJournalDate is null OR DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Final30DayJournalDate) < getdate()) AND
           (@Final30DayDecisonDate is null OR DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Final30DayDecisonDate) < getdate()) AND
           (@Final6MonthDecisonDate is null OR DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Final6MonthDecisonDate) < getdate()) AND
              DATEADD(DAY, 14, @DecisionDueDate) > DATEADD(DAY, 30, getdate()))
                  SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, -30, @DecisionDueDate)
      ELSE
         BEGIN
              IF((@Final30DayJournalDate is not null ) AND (DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Final30DayJournalDate) >= @DecisionDueDate))
                  SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DecisionDueDate)

              IF((@Final30DayDecisonDate is not null ) AND (DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Final30DayDecisonDate) >= @DecisionDueDate))
            SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @DecisionDueDate)

              IF((@Final6MonthDecisonDate is not null ) AND (DATEADD(DAY, 30, @Final6MonthDecisonDate) >= @DecisionDueDate))
                 SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @DecisionDueDate)
      END          
END
ELSE IF @CurrentStatus = '4' AND @CheckDate = 0
BEGIN

   DECLARE @InactiveBaseSupplementDate DateTime
   DECLARE @LastInactiveBaseSupplementDate DateTime
   DECLARE @LastInactiveJournalDate DateTime

   SELECT @InactiveBaseSupplementDate = (SELECT TOP 1  idps.BaseSupplementDate
                                              FROM EventDetails_Supplements idps 
                                              INNER JOIN EventDetails p ON idps.PageId = p.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN IncidentDetailsPage_Incident idp ON idps.PageId = p.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                              WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND 
                                                             r.BaseId = @BaseId AND idp.IncidentStatus = '4' ORDER BY idps.BaseSupplementDate ASC)

        SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(Month, 6, @InactiveBaseSupplementDate)

           WHILE @DecisionDueDate < getdate() 
             SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(Month, 6, @DecisionDueDate)



        SELECT @LastInactiveBaseSupplementDate = (SELECT TOP 1  idps.BaseSupplementDate
                                              FROM EventDetails_Supplements idps 
                                              INNER JOIN EventDetails p ON idps.PageId = p.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN IncidentDetailsPage_Incident idp ON idps.PageId = p.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                              WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND 
                                                             r.BaseId = @BaseId AND idp.IncidentStatus = '4' AND idps.IsInactiveReview = 1 ORDER BY idps.BaseSupplementDate DESC)

        SELECT @LastInactiveJournalDate = (SELECT TOP 1 ij.Date
                                              FROM EventDetails_Journal ij 
                                              INNER JOIN EventJournal p ON ij.PageId = p.Id 
                                              INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id
                                              INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                              WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND 
                                              r.BaseId = @BaseId AND  ij.ReviewType = 'Inactive' ORDER BY ij.Date DESC)

      IF(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @InactiveBaseSupplementDate) < getdate() AND
           (@LastInactiveJournalDate is null OR DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @LastInactiveBaseSupplementDate) < getdate()) AND
           (@LastInactiveBaseSupplementDate is null OR DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @LastInactiveJournalDate) < getdate()) AND
              DATEADD(DAY, 14, @DecisionDueDate) > DATEADD(MONTH, 6, getdate()))
                  SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(Month, -6, @DecisionDueDate)
      ELSE
         BEGIN
              if((@LastInactiveBaseSupplementDate is not null ) AND (DATEADD(Month, 6, @LastInactiveBaseSupplementDate) >= @DecisionDueDate))
                       SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(Month, 6, @DecisionDueDate)

              if((@LastInactiveJournalDate is not null ) AND (DATEADD(Month, 6, @LastInactiveJournalDate) >= @DecisionDueDate))
                       SET @DecisionDueDate = DATEADD(Month, 6, @DecisionDueDate)          
         END
END

END


GO
```

As you can see i have multiple if condition and i was able to convert one if condition as shown below.
I converted the first part with condition 
`IF @CurrentStatus IN ('0','6') AND @CheckDate = 1`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEventDecisionDueDate_test1]
(
       @EventNumber VARCHAR(20),
       @AgencyOri VARCHAR(25),
          @CheckDate BIT
)

RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN
     WITH X 
          AS (SELECT cis.IncidentStatus AS CurrentIncidentStatus,
                     r.BaseDateTime,
                     FROM CurrentIncidentStatus cis 
                     INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (cis.BaseId = r.Id)
                     WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber) AND r.AgencyOri = @AgencyOri
                     AND cis.IncidentStatus IN ('0','6')
                     AND @CheckDate = 1)
    SELECT X.CurrentIncidentStatus,
           X.BaseDateTime,
           CA4.DecisionDueDate
    FROM X
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, 30, X.BaseDateTime))) CA1(DecisionDueDate)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, 30 * CEILING(( IIF(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) > CAST(CA1.DecisionDueDate AS TIME), 1, 0)
                                                    + DATEDIFF(DAY, CA1.DecisionDueDate, GETDATE()) ) / 30.0), CA1.DecisionDueDate))) CA2(DecisionDueDate)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ij.Date
                                       FROM EventDetails_Journal ij 
                                       INNER JOIN EventJournal p ON ij.PageId = p.Id 
                                       INNER JOIN Journal f ON p.JournalId = f.Id 
                                       INNER JOIN Base r WITH (NOLOCK) ON (f.BaseId = r.Id)
                                       WHERE (r.EventNumber = @EventNumber AND r.AgencyOri = @AgencyOri) AND 
                                       ij.ReviewType = 'Supervisor Monthly Review' ORDER BY ij.Date DESC) CA3(IncidentJournalDate)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES ( CASE
                          WHEN ( DATEADD(DAY, 30, X.BaseDateTime) < GETDATE()
                                 AND ( CA3.IncidentJournalDate IS NULL
                                        OR DATEADD(DAY, 30, CA3.IncidentJournalDate) < GETDATE() )
                                 AND DATEADD(DAY, 14, CA2.DecisionDueDate) > DATEADD(DAY, 30, GETDATE()) )
                            THEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, CA2.DecisionDueDate)
                          WHEN( ( CA3.IncidentJournalDate IS NOT NULL )
                                AND ( DATEADD(DAY, 30, CA3.IncidentJournalDate) >= CA2.DecisionDueDate ) )
                            THEN DATEADD(DAY, 30, CA2.DecisionDueDate)
                          ELSE CA2.DecisionDueDate
                        END )) CA4(DecisionDueDate); 
GO
```

I will try to make it simple.
if someone can help me,to include all the conditional logic into one function that would be helpful.

Comment: I wonder if SQL Server 2019 would automatically [inline this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=azuresqldb-current) :)

Comment: Might not be a good idea in the first place. I think this gets rid of the `while` loops and related logic: `dateadd(day, (30 - datediff(day, DecisionDueDate, getdate()) mod 30) mod 30, getdate())`

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the same transformation for second part using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (-- all nested logic here
     )
WHERE @CurrentStatus IN ('0','6') AND @CheckDate = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (-- rest of nested logic here
     )
WHERE @CurrentStatus = '4' AND @CheckDate = 0
```

Comment: I want only one block of code to execute and with UNION ALL i get result from all three right?

Comment: @user9516827 No you don't get result of all three blocks. Simply because you have WHERE clause with distintive conditions based on params: `WHERE @CurrentStatus IN ('0','6') AND @CheckDate = 1` or `WHERE @CurrentStatus = '4' AND @CheckDate = 0`. They cannot be true the same time

Comment: I agreee to that i can use union all within the CTE ,but the logic outside  CTE is different for each condition (or each UNION ALL ).How do i handle that.

Comment: @user9516827 By not nesting it, you could build on top of specifiic UNION part any logic

Comment: `WITH X
 AS (
 (select ...
 .........
 where condition 1)
 select X....
UNION ALL
 (select ...
 .........
 where condition 2)
 select X....
UNION ALL
  (select ...
 .........
 where condition )
 select X....
     )` Is this what you are trying to say.? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @user9516827 Yes That is the idea.

Comment: Szozda That won't work  as i CTE is complete in the last parenthesis only. After first `(select ...........where conditon 1)`  i cannot access X.column ...as CTE is not complete at that point.